# How to securely store credentials needed in a profile.d script?

Tags: security, login, password, startup, profile

**Disclaimer:**

I'm working on Ubuntu 20.04, but I assume my question is unrelated to a specific Linux distribution.
I've searched the Internet for quite some time and found lots of other similar questions and answers but nothing particular about my specific problem.

**What I want to do:**

I have a script which I would like to run when a user logs in (via ssh or console).
Therefore I think I have to put a script in /etc/profile.d
This script needs credentials to run, lets say a token to make a REST-Call via curl.
The credentials needed are the same for all users, they are not user specific.
I do not want the user to see the credentials.

**What my problem seems to be:**

Scripts in /etc/profile.d seem to run under the user account logging in.
If I store credentials in an environment variable the user could see it.
If I store credentials in a file the user needs to be able to read the file, because otherwise the script could not read them.
If I store credentials in a database I need credentials to access the database and face my initial problem just with another password.

**What I came up with:**

I run the script indirectly via sudo as root accessing a credentials file only readable as root:

I've added a script /etc/profile.d/run-my-script.sh containing `sudo my-script.sh $USER`.
(`$USER`is needed to know in `m̀y-script.sh` who initially logged in)
Then I did a `chmod 600 my-script.sh` (owner root) and stored my credentials in a file `.credentials` (also chmod 600, owner root).

In `my-script.sh` I read the credentials from the file `read TOKEN < /etc/profile.d/.credentials` and at the end of the run I do an `unset TOKEN`.

Finally I added via visudo

```
ALL     ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/profile.d/other-script.sh
```

**My question:**

Even though my 'solution' works it feels clumsy for something which is very likely a common problem.
Is there an easier way to achieve the same effect?
Did I miss a loophole and does my solution leak credentials in an unexpected way?

Thanks.

Comment: You could hardcode the secret in the script. The set user and group to root and chmod 711. Then the script is only executable for world but not readable.  Only the root user can edit or read it. But do you take care on logging? Curl e.g. could log the url inclusive the secret or `ps -ef` could print the command line while the process is still running.

Comment: I also don't think this is a common use case. Most admins don't want to allow more than one user perform action with a common secret / identity. No one can be made responsiblke for fraud. ;-)

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer Thanks for your comment. The script doesn't need the executable flag in profile.d (it is sourced). If the script is not readable for the user it won't run. If it is readable the user could see the credentials. The use case is that the login of any user is audited and the data (time, ip etc) must be transferred to another system. This is done via curl. So technically the user is not in need of own credentials.
Thanks for mentioning `ps -ef`. I'll have a look into that.

Comment: Are you sure you must source the file? If you add a she bang on top e.g. `#! /bin/bash` you can simply run it as a command in a bash for example `/path/to/the/script.h` . As long as a command (e,g source or .) that is executed for a user needs to read the file, you'll have not really a chance to hide it from the user..

Comment: I have another idea. You could create a script that performs the curl call. Source a secret script from it to set the secrets the env variables. Both scripts must belong to the user and group root and only theroot has full access `chmod 700` for both files. Then set the user setuid bit for the curl script `chmod  u+s`. Then the curl script is executed as the owner (root). The curl script runs in it own environment. Only root has access to the env vars. The process list could still be a problem. And the setuid bit is a security risk if someone can manipulate the curl script or the sec-script.